# Mockjax dynamic mock stops working with `dataType="Script"`

Tags: javascript, mockjax

I have a dynamic mock setup using mockjax, and it works for most of my ajax requests, but fails when the `dataType` is set to `Script`, and lets the request fall through to regular Ajax handler.

```
// gets mocked
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://myurl.com/myfile.js?_=1395314460347"
})

// does not get mocked!
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
    url: "http://myurl.com/myfile.js?_=1395314460347"
})
```

How can I configure dynamic mocks in mockjax to intercept requests with the `dataType` set?

---

#### UPDATE: example code for mockjax definition

I am creating dynamic mock, so I am defining via function, not plain object, something like this...

```
$.mockjax(function(settings) {
  // settings.url == '/restful/<service>'
  var service = settings.url.match(/\/restful\/(.*)$/);
  if ( service ) {
    return {
      proxy: '/mocks/' + service[1] + '.json',
      // handle `dataType: 'script'`
      dataType: 'application/javascript'
    };
  }
  return;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug with how Mockjax handles crossDomain script requests. It is not doing anything special to detect the crossDomain request (like it does with JSONP) and as such, when it passes the request back to the original `$.ajax` method – jQuery never uses the mocked up XHR object it was provided by Mockjax.

So in essence, Mockjax is intercepting the request, and then passes it right back to jQuery and it fails on you.

I opened an issue here so this can be fixed: https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax/issues/136

In the mean time you have a two choices. If you want to quickly patch mockjax, add this line to around 471:

```
origSettings.crossDomain = false;
```

That section will look like this when you are done:

```
mockHandler.cache = requestSettings.cache;
mockHandler.timeout = requestSettings.timeout;
mockHandler.global = requestSettings.global;

origSettings.crossDomain = false;

copyUrlParameters(mockHandler, origSettings);
```

The other alternative (which I recommend against), is adding `crossDomain: false` to your actual AJAX request. I don't recommend this due to the need to remove that line when you remove your mocks later.

Thanks @Nicholas Cloud for pinging me and bringing this issue to my attention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the `dataType` property *in your mocked endpoints*?

See: https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax#data-types

If you are, have you tried setting the mock dataType to `application/javascript`?

```
$.mockjax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "application/javascript",
    url: "myfile.js?_=1395314460347",
    responseText: "(function () { alert('hello world!'); }());"
});

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
    url: "myfile.js?_=1395314460347"
});
```

Comment: I updated the question, I am defining in function call, and have set the dataType in the object returned by the function. I have logged to console to check it is as expected. Any more ideas? Thanks.

Comment: If you are returning json it will need to be `application/json` for the dataType, I believe (or just shorthand `json`).

Comment: I am returning javascript.

Comment: @BillyMoon can you please confirm that your function is *actually* returning the object literal, and not falling through to the final return? If it returns false (or undefined), the native AJAX call will be invoked.

Comment: Also, in your example you are returning a JSON file as a javascript file:

proxy: '/mocks/' + service[1] + '.json',
// handle `dataType: 'script'`
dataType: 'application/javascript'